# Does using JOINS also have performance improvement

Tags: d3.js

I am thinking about the scatter plot ... a diagram with many circles on it. Let's say 5000 circles on it.
Then I see some code that say Ok here is how you draw "one" circle with D3, now I want 5000 of those and each of them is one DOM right? 
So will the browser crash or can it handle this? And then I came arocss this blog post 
http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/
That explains JONIS....
So does it mean if I use JOINS then I won't need to create 5000 separate circles and performance will improve drastically? or it is just a good syntax and still performance is the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joins just mean that if you load some new data, then you will be able to separate easily: the new circles (`selection.enter()`), deleted circles (`selection.exit()`) and all circles (`selection`).!

In the following image, the elements correspond to the data that has already been loaded and the data to the new data which you will use to create new circles.

[Elements vs data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zMAA.png)

So, you will still load 5000 separate circles. But, if you update only one circle, then you won't redraw the 5000 circles by using `selection.enter()`. So, by using wisely this tool you can improve performance for dynamic visualizations.